# XPathExpression return null if attribute not found

Tags: java, xml-parsing

simple expression

```
 private static final XPathExpression SOME_NUMBER = newXPathExpression(
            ".//some/number/text()"
    );
```

and evaluating

```
return (String) SOME_NUMBER.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

i want return null if argument number not found in XML document instead of empty string

i know i can check empty string by myself - but in my case i need separate argument with no value = empty, argument not foud = null